# Proof: If A is diagonalizable, then the rank(A) = number of nonzero eigenvalues of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have tried to prove it as follows:

Suppose A is a $nxn$ matrix. It's  eigenvalues are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$, with $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_r\ne0$, and $\lambda_{r+1}=...=\lambda_n=0$, so A has r nonzero eigenvalues.

Since A is diagonalizable, there exists a inverse matrix S such that $
S^{-1}AS=D=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&0&0\\0&\lambda_2&0&0\\0&0&\ddots &0\\0&0&0&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$

I'm stuck here, so how could I go from here to prove: $rank(A) = rank(D) = r$?

Comment: Do you know how to find the rank of a matrix in general? As in, if we were looking at a *specific* matrix with numerical entries, how would you find its rank?

Comment: As a hint, why is it *particularly easy* to find the rank of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom After applying Gaussian-elimination, the number of pivots = the rank of the matrix. So in a diagonal matrix, the rank would just be the number of non-zero entries along the diagonal. So rank(D) = r. But what about rank(A) = rank(D)?

Comment: Multiplying $A$ by an invertible matrix does not change its rank

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So I suppose multiplying A by the inverse of an invertible matrix does not change its rank as well? I have seen proofs on why multiplying by an invertible matrix doesn't change rank, so can we apply the same logic to multiplying by the inverse of an invertible matrix?Thanks.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think I got it now. Thanks again!